# Problem in passing dictionary parameter to render template as Argument Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to send a list of books objects to my template to display their names and images.Here is my book class

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zonar=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book_id=models.IntegerField(default=10)
    image=models.ImageField()
    file=models.FileField(upload_to="cars",default="")
```

Here is my django view

```
def books_display(request,zonar):
    ###########
    ###########
    zonar_books=Book.objects.filter(zonar=zonar)
    books={"zonar":zonar,"zonar_books":zonar_books}

    return render(request,"books/books_listed.html",books)
```

finally this is my template

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      {% if zonar %}
      {{ zonar }}
      {%endif%}
       books </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if zonar_books %}
    {% for book in zonar_books %}
    <h1>{{ book.tile}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  </body>
</html>
```

And iam getting following error

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Sriram\Desktop\books_site\books\templates\books\books_listed.html, error at line 12

no such column: books_book.zonar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you did not apply migrations

Try to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` (you should know it)

And use `{{ book.title }}`, instead of `{{ book.tile }}`

It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try {{ book.title }} instead {{ book.tile}}.